# Произношение слова "денег" (р. п.)

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

Поскольку никто не отвечает на добавок к другому вопросу, вынесу его отдельно.

Можно ли произносить слово "денег" (в р. п.) именно с Х — [день**х**]? Просто вспомнил, что сам так обычно говорю.

*И заодно ещё спрошу:* "кто" говорят как [**х**то] ***исключительно*** ради шутки, или нет? :)

Comment: Знаю, что не ответ, потому пишу здесь... Я отнёс бы "дених-деньх" к тому же гхэканию, как и "бог", "дог". Никакой разницы я не услеживаю.  Что касается "хто", то это либо диалект, либо просторечие.

Comment: Про Бога (и богов) все писали, что говорить Х или мягкое Г правильно, п. ч. это исключение! Так что не смешивайте его с догом и прочим. Так ведь Вы ж то мне и ссылку дали!))

Comment: Артем, в словарях обычно оговаривается то или иное исключение. Но ни в одном словаре не сказано, что можно произносить дене/х/.

Answer (score 2):

По правилам орфоэпии  в конце слова и перед глухими согласными Г произносится как К. В орфоэпических словарях указываются только исключения - Бо[х]. Про вариант [хто]  сказано, что не допускается в строгой литературной речи.

http://www.studfiles.ru/preview/1549391/

"В русской речи происходит обязательное оглушение звонких согласных в конце слова. Мы произносим хле[п] – хлеб, са[т] – сад, смо[к] – смог, и т.д. Это оглушение является одним из характерных признаков русской литературной речи. Нужно учесть, что согласный [г] в конце слова всегда переходит в парный ему глухой звук [к]: лё[к] – лёг, дене[к] – денег и т.д. Произнесение в этом случае звука [х] недопустимо как диалектное: лё[х], дене[х]. Исключение составляет слово Бог - Бо[х]".

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Вера! Но Вы меня огорчили. Надеялся, что это может считаться если не основным, то хотя бы разговорным (или не знаю каким ещё) допустимым вариантом. ;)

Comment: У меня сведения из словаря Резниченко(2010 год). Может быть, в других источниках указано не такое строгое предписание.

Comment: Будем надеяться.)